# Why is Resize-Partition not working in WinPE?

Tags: windows, partitioning, powershell

I'm currently playing around with making my 'own' MDT / Deployment Software using PowerShell and encountered an issue that I can't find any information to. Basically I already created the EFI, MSR and Windows Partition and want to shrink the Windows Partition using PowerShell so that I can create the Recovery Partition.

I tried resizing / shrinking the Windows Partition using the Resize-Partition function in PowerShell, but it doesn't seem to do anything... I know you can use for example `diskpart`, but I would prefer a PowerShell way since I already create all the Partitions and apply the install.wim using PowerShell.

[image: Resize-Partition in WinPE]

Everything is done in VMware Workstation for testing purposes.

Why is Resize-Partition not working at all?

Comment: Please don't add text as an image.

Comment: @Dominique Thx for letting me know!
How should I handle it in the future? Because I wasn't able to copy & paste it since it was in a VM and I wanted to show the output, so you can see that the Partition Size isn't changing.

Comment: Have you installed Windows on the partition, or is it empty?

Comment: @harrymc All partitions are empty